# Long range RFID

Tags: rfid

Do you know which technology can have better range with and without battery assitance than RFID?

This is for a school project, we are looking for ways to detect crab traps lost in the sea.

We thought on passive RFID but then found it has a very small range.

Thanks

Comment: You are not saying (among other things) how much range you would like.

Comment: @NickAlexeev the longest possible, at least 500m

Comment: Longest possible, you say.  In that case, how about [Iridium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation)?

Comment: +1 for a good question.  I can't imagine why anyone would want to downvote it other than not having a clue.

Comment: @EMFields   I can't imagine why anyone would want to upvote this.  Reasons to downvote.  (1) It's an academic assignment.  The O.P. haven' demonstrated his own effort.  (2) He did not characterize the problem.  Underwater, or on the surface?  What's the required distance?  How long does it have to work?  How will it be used?  How much who cares why?  As a result we are sent on a wild goose chase anywhere between RFID, Iridium, VLF and SONAR.

Comment: Crab traps (creels) are weighted and, unless badly broken, sink. So, underwater. They are commonly connected to a buoy, but if they are still connected to it, they aren't lost.

Comment: @NickAlexeev,  1.) I wasn't aware that answering a request for help  with an academic assignment wasn't allowed, especially since the OP specified an unsuccessful approach that had already been considered. 2.) Since crabs don't fly, it seems fairly obvious that he's talking about an underwater application. 3.) "What's the required distance?" and "How long does it have to work?" are both  good questions and, as I understand it, questions in comments are supposed to be used to more clearly define the OP's requirements, not to browbeat him.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: 4.) I believe he said that its use would be to "locate crab traps lost in the sea."  5. I don't understand what you mean by "How much who cares why?" but it doesn't sound very nice at all.  And, finally, 5.) Since SONAR is the only viable solution, I fail to see how examining and then rejecting irrelevant candidate  technologies constitutes a "wild goose chase".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By and large, RF (particularly RFID) simply won't work underwater, particularly at the depths associated with crab pots. [RF attenuation of seawater](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijdsn/2013/508708/) is just too great. Note figure 7 of the paper. At 1 MHz, attenuation is ~40dB/m, and pots at 100 meters down simply aren't going to hear a transmitter of any reasonable power, much less retransmit their IDs. Going to longer wavelengths helps, but not a whole lot.

Nuclear subs managed to listen for radio signals while submerged, but they used extremely low frequencies, long (100 meter) antennas, and bit rates in the vicinity of 1 bit/second. Not exactly useful for your application.

Comment: Is there any other technology beacon-like or something that someone can use to find lost pots?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  Near field RF communication (say, 13 MHz) can work through water.  For example, it's used for communicating with implants.  However, the useful range of near field RF is comparatively short, because it's near field.

Comment: @JorgeeFG - Sonar would work, but not without active electronics. You could put a microphone, power source (battery) and pinger, so the pot would make noise when it heard a beacon. And that's exactly how it's done in airliner black boxes, so it can be made to work well. But it's expensive.

Answer (score 2):

A technique that's been used for many years is to attach a SONAR transponder to  the target, sink it, and then interrogate it from a surface vessel.

In use, once the surface vessel acquires the synthetic echo from the transponder, it traverses a grid until the time between the surface ping and the transponder's response is minimized. When that happens - assuming the surface vessel's transducer is pointing straight downward - the target will be directly below the surface vessel.